# For PhD admissions is it better to be a first author on a workshop paper or a co-author on a conference paper

Tags: phd, application

In computer science being first author means you basically did all the work whereas if co-author does not indicate what amount of work is done. Which would be more well received on an application to PhD programs?

Comment: Actually, if first authors means you basically did all the work, then clearly co-author (meaning not-first-author) also says something about the contribution (that it was hardly there). This is definitely not the correct way to interpret author ordering in computer science in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to be the first author on the *highest quality* paper, regardless of workshop, conference, or journal publication.

Answer (score 1):

The first author is not always the author of correspondence. In some cases, authors are alphabetically ordered. Nevertheless, it is a common notion that first authors are always considered to have the major contribution.

Coming back to your question, it is true that PhD admissions are more interested in papers with being the corresponding author.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question, which is about PhD admission.

Comment: Edit confirmed.

Answer (score 1):

While is usually true that first authors count more (I had a grant declined once citing that as a reason, but not on computer science), do not try to trick the committee...

What really counts is the whole of your publication history, that should have good papers, published in the appropriate venue.

Don't pass on networking options just because you will not be first author... Ideally, you should have both: articles directly derived from your work (thesis/project) with you as first author as well as articles that are related to your work (but derived from someone else's project, for instance) that you collaborated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that all the answer we can really give you is: "It depends."
The reasons are:

- It's not really possible to tell the relative amount of contribution of an undergraduate from their position as first or second author.  Typically the first author has contributed the most, but with inexperienced researchers there may be so much coaching involved that the value of first author is somewhat diluted.  Likewise, the second author might have contributed very little or might have contributed only a tiny bit less than the first author.
- The value of a conference vs. a workshop depends a lot on the conference and the workshop and the paper.  A paper in a high-quality and well-respected workshop will be much better than in a poor conference.  Likewise, a marginal paper can sometimes get into a decent conference, while excellent papers are sometimes sent to workshops because it's the right place for them, for various reasons.

The real thing that will explain the value that you have contributed to a paper to an admissions committee is a letter of recommendation, from a person who knows the work you did.